# Setting a correct angular velocity to a canvas object

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I am building a space shooter game and would like the ship to fire rockets at the direction of the cursor. Therefore, I grab the radian value of the angle it should fire at, multiply it by the ship's speed and set it's x and y velocities respectively.

I have this as a Bullet class:

```
function Bullet(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.width = 6;
    this.height = 3;
    this.color = utils.getRandomColor();
    this.speed = 80;
}
```

And here is the function which updates the movement of all instances of the bullet class:

```
function drawBullet(bullet) {
    var dx = mouse.x - bullet.x,
        dy = mouse.y - bullet.y,
        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    bullet.vx = Math.cos(angle) * bullet.speed;
    bullet.vy = Math.sin(angle) * bullet.speed;
    bullet.x += bullet.vx;
    bullet.y += bullet.vy;
    bullet.draw(ctx);
}
```

It starts okay, going in the right direction and velocity and stuff. But as soon as it reaches the mouse, it stops dead there and starts flickering. NOW, I realise that this is because of the way I am getting the angle, using the mouse position as a value - the problem is that I can't figure out a way to use just the angle for the velocity, not the distance to the mouse position. So it doesn't slow down.

All suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to happen when the bullet reaches its target (the mouse)?

Comment: Nothing, that's the problem. I want the bullet to fly right through the mouse and out of the screen with a constant x and y velocities (when this happens, I will splice it out of the array)

Comment: I see...maybe do something like this: The bullet collides with the mouse when dx+dy nears zero. When impact happens, instead of recomputing a new angle just pull the last "non-impact" angle out of the bullet object. Save the last non-impact angle using `bullet.lastNonImpactAngle=angle;` inside drawBullet().

Comment: I don't get it, is the bullet supposed to be like a homing missile, always following your mouse cursor?

Comment: No, when a mouse is clicked, I want to fire the bullet at the angle  corresponding to the current mouse position with fixed velocities. As it is fired, if it doesn't hit anything, it goes out of the canvas and I remove it. No following the mouse or fancy stuff like this

Comment: @markE, I tried this approach and unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: So then, why not just save the angle you got right on the mouse click and re-use it later?  `bullet.angle = angle;`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need homing missile type behavior just pass the mouse coordinates when you create the bullet.

**Example:**

`new Bullet(shooterX, shooterY, mouseX, mouseY)`

I included an over engineered stack snippet but the relevant part is below.

```
var Bullet = function(x,y,tx,ty){
    this.speed = 15;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    var radians = Math.atan2(ty-y, tx-x);
    // we now have our velX and velY we can just refer to
    this.velX = Math.cos(radians) * this.speed;
    this.velY = Math.sin(radians) * this.speed;

}

Bullet.prototype.update = function(){
    // just update by our previous calculated velX and velY.
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.y += this.velY;
};
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 250,
    height = 250,
    output = document.getElementById("radians"),
    output2 = document.getElementById("degrees"),
    cX = 0,
    cY = 0,
    mX = 0,
    mY = 0,
    bullets = [];

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    mX = e.pageX;
    mY = e.pageY;
});

var Ball = function (x, y, radius, color) {    
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.radius = radius || 10;
    
    // makes our x and y the center of the circle.
    this.x = (this.x-this.radius/2);
    this.y = (this.y-this.radius/2);
    
    // how far out do we want the point
    this.pointLength = 50;
    this.px = 0;
    this.py = 0;
    
    this.color = color || "rgb(255,0,0)";
}

Ball.prototype.shoot = function(tx, ty){
    bullets.push(new Bullet(this.x, this.y, tx, ty));
}

Ball.prototype.update = function (x, y) {
    // get the target x and y
    this.targetX = x;
    this.targetY = y;
    
    var x = this.x - this.targetX,
        y = this.y - this.targetY,
        radians = Math.atan2(y,x);
    
    this.px = this.x - this.pointLength * Math.cos(radians);
    this.py = this.y - this.pointLength * Math.sin(radians);
    
    // -y will make 0 the top, y will 0 us at the bottom.
    output.textContent = radians;
    output2.textContent = radians/Math.PI * 180
};

Ball.prototype.render = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,255)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.px, this.py);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
};

var Bullet = function(x,y,tx,ty){
    this.speed = 15;
    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    
    var radians = Math.atan2(ty-y, tx-x);
    this.velX = Math.cos(radians) * this.speed;
    this.velY = Math.sin(radians) * this.speed;

}

Bullet.prototype.update = function(){
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.y += this.velY;
};

Bullet.prototype.render = function(){
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
};

var ball1 = new Ball(width/2, height/2, 10);

canvas.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    ball1.shoot(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ball1.update(mX, mY);
    ball1.render();
    
    bullets.forEach(function(b){
        b.update();
        b.render();
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```css
ol{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <span>Radians : </span><span id="radians"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Degrees : </span><span id="degrees"></span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new property on `bullet` that stores the angle of motion, initialize it to `-1`.  Then, on the very first `drawBullet` call, check if it has been initialized first.  If not, set the angle...

```
function Bullet(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.width = 6;
    this.height = 3;
    this.color = utils.getRandomColor();
    this.speed = 80;
    this.angle = -1;                // New, angle property initialized to -1
}

function drawBullet(bullet) {
    if (bullet.angle === -1) {      // Only pull the mouse cursor and get an angle
      var dx = mouse.x - bullet.x,  // If it hasn't already done so.
          dy = mouse.y - bullet.y,
          angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      bullet.angle = angle;
    }
    bullet.vx = Math.cos(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed;  // Re-use the angle value.
    bullet.vy = Math.sin(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed;
    bullet.x += bullet.vx;
    bullet.y += bullet.vy;
    bullet.draw(ctx);
}
```

Comment: You can't understand the logic behind saving the angle and re-using it?

Comment: My bad, man, it works flawlessly! Still, can you explain me the logic behind this?

Comment: If EVERY draw, you pull the mouse cursor AGAIN, potentially that means every time you move the mouse, the bullet will follow it around.  Also, this means that as soon as the bullet crosses the mouse position, the angle immediately flips backwards to go BACK towards the mouse, which is behind it now, so it turns around... over and over again

Comment: I see, so basicaly by setting the angle to - 1 and making the check for the mouse pos only once, the bullet is fired in this direction with a fixed target, right?

Comment: Not with a fixed target, but with a fixed direction.  It gets the direction to the target initially, but then it no longer cares about the target, it only cares about going forward.  The only reason you would not want this is if you actually wanted a homing bullet that continually changed directions to follow a moving target.